# Creating empty integer/decimal column by using Select

Tags: sql

I'm creating an empty column in my table, when I use '' as columnname, it created empty column but String type. How can I create empty column but Integer/decimal type?

Null as columnname doesn't work!
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about .Could you please add more details?

Comment: That's what `NULL` is for

Comment: In creating the table, how can I add a NULL column by using SELECT? (empty column with Null)

Comment: Normally if we write

SELECT *, ' ' as C_name

an empty column named C_name will be added to the table, but in this way the value is String, how can I create Decimal?

Another example:
Select *, 0 as C_name 
created a column with all 0 values

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "creating an empty column in my table"? Do you want to create a real empty column in an existing database table? Or do you just want to include an empty column in the results of a SELECT query? (I already provided an answer for the latter case.)

Answer (score 2):

Adding an INT column with NULLs inside a SELECT query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(NULL AS INT) AS columnname
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet which creates a new empty column of INT datatype

`ALTER TABLE schema.tablename ADD column_a INT NULL ;`

Comment: Done.Thankyou for guiding a new bee.@Dima Kozhevin

Comment: @DimaKozhevin I don't think this answers the OP's question. The OP talks about "creating an empty column in my table", but as a SELECT is mentioned, I assume an extra column in a SELECT query's result's "table" is meant.

Answer (score -1):

You can create empty column of  integer type and null is not a string value:

```
SELECT
  hat,
  shoe,
  boat,
  0 as placeholder for number
FROM table
```

And `''` as placeholder for strings.

And `null` as placeholder for null value.